# I have date with this format in my db '1631363150' i want to change it to dd-mm-yyyy (DART)

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

**I have date with this format in my db '1631363150' i want to change it to  dd-mm-yyyy (DART)**

Comment: could you tell in what format `1631363150` is?

Comment: probably Unix time, in seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC.

Comment: @MrFuppes i think yes but this year is not 1970

Comment: the UNIX epoch is 1970-01-01 UTC, so if this is *not* your reference date, then it's not Unix time ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try if it would be your reference time

```
void main() {
   var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1631363150 * 1000);
   print("get time: ${DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(date)}");
}
output: get time: 11-09-2021
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly

Comment: please for the opposite i want this date 2021-10-22 15:36:06.609824 => with this format 1631363150

Comment: try with this `print(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);`